# Android video captured in portrait mode is not playing in portrait mode

Tags: android, video, media

In my app there I am capturing video in portrait mode but the video is by default changing to landscape when I play it.

I tried `mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90)` worked in Android 4.0 devices but not in 2.3 devices. My App target is 2.3

I have also noticed one thing that when I go to Gallery and play it through the default media player it plays in Portait mode. :-(

Try various options and I goggled around but couldn't find any solution. Please someone guide me if you have ever faced the same issue.

here's my Code

```
mMediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();

    mCamera.unlock();
    mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
    mMediaRecorder.setCamera(mCamera);

    mMediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
    mMediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
    mMediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(30);
```

Comment: I tried de-compile an APK. They have used NDK. Is it required ??

Answer (score 0):

It seems it cannot record video in other way than landscape. Your mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90) is affecting preview according to the docs.